# Button getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS by method with ivars

Tags: uiimageview, exc-bad-access, retaincount

I'm neophyte in obj-c, so I cant understand some of this logic. I want to understand my code and app logic. My app is modification of easy example with animation of UIImageView: this's .h (in standart view-based template)

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ImageAnimatorViewController : UIViewController {
    UIImageView *animImage;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *animImage;
- (IBAction)startAnimation;
- (NSArray*)creatAnimation:(NSString*)fileName;
@end
```

this's .m (without standart dealloc and viewDidUnload)

```
@synthesize animImage;
- (IBAction)startAnimation{
    [animImage startAnimating];
}    
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    animImage.animationImages = [self creatAnimation:@"Images.jpg"]; 
    animImage.animationDuration = 1.0f; 
    animImage.animationRepeatCount = 0; 
}    
- (NSArray*)creatAnimation:(NSString*)fileName{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
    NSMutableArray *animationImages = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i<8; i++) {
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(image.CGImage, 
        CGRectMake(i*600.0f, 0.0f, 600.0f, 262.0f));
        UIImage *animationImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    [animationImages addObject:animationImage];
    [animationImage release];
    }
    return animationImages;
}
```

Also i've xib with imageview and button, but when i pressed b there's crash and EXC_BAD_ACCESS in console. In IBAction I understand imageView hasn't animationImages, but why? and has strange reference count = 3,because in viewDidLoad has 2(and why 2?). I add self and self-> prefix in viewDidLoad, but it's no result. animationImages is (copy) property,so images saves after autorelease pool is drained with animationImages. I'm very surprised about this behavior of app.10x!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not release **animationImage** in **createAnimation** method. You also should clean memory for **CGImageRef** using **CGImageRelease**

Comment: Thank you very much, it's work. But can you explain your answer? For me I have memory leaks, because animationImage has more reference count than it needs. What is hidden from me?)

Comment: In short. You should release object if you creates it with **alloc**, **new**, **retain**, **copy**. You didn't use nothing of them to create animationImage, so no reason to release animationImage. I can advice you to read base Memory management rules.          ps. If my answer is right and useful to you then, please, accept it by click on green tick on the left.